# threshold in AchartEngine?

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I am new to android, and I have been using AChartEngine to make graphs
I would like to know if there any way to set a threshold line for a graph in AchartEngine?

An example might be to have thresholds in a temperature chart at 32 degrees F and 212 degrees F. Below 32 the line could be one color, it could be a different color between 32 and 212 and another color above 212.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with bar charts by enabling the gradient and setting the start and stop gradient colors, but not with line charts.